# Can not start Kibana on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I use elasticsearch and i installed kibana for visualize data.
The first time, kibana run well.
I stopped kibana.
And then, i can not start kibana again.

Please help me!
Thanks!

I tried some solutions on the internet, but they not work.